# Listener Facebook Login in Supabase Flutter

Tags: flutter, supabase

I'm research about supabase in flutter.
I using Login with Facebook.

```
 await client.auth.signInWithOAuth(Provider.facebook);
```

but, this function auto return ```true``, even when I don't open webview.

How can I listen to the results returned from facebook.

Answer (score 0):

For non-web platforms, you have to [setup deep links](https://pub.dev/packages/supabase_flutter#deep-link-config), and redirect the user back to the app after signing in using deep links.

```dart
 await client.auth.signInWithOAuth(Provider.facebook, redirecTo: 'io.supabase.flutterdemo://callback');
```